# Is there a way to disable the local maven repository?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven, nexus

This may sound crazy but we have our developers all working on the same Linux machine, this machine also has nexus installed as our maven repo. Effectively everyone ends up with artefacts in their ~/.m2/ folder which are also duplicated in the nexus server.

Is it possible to simply tell maven to only look at the artefacts in nexus?

I have for the moment set the property `<localRepository>/path/to/global/repo</localRepository>` in our global maven config, but unsure if this could cause a problem if two users are grabbing the same file at the same time.

We do this because the company won't buy us powerful workstations so we all ssh to our development server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't want to point my local repo to the nexus datastore, because then installs would update the repository datastore behind nexus' back.

However you could set up a single "machine" local repo separate to the nexus datastore,
and then for each user change the `~/.m2/repository` directory to be a symlink pointing to the "machine" local repo.

At least then you'll only have 2 copies of the repo.

Concurrent installs and downloads, are still likely to clobber one another, but this can be fixed with an annoying redo.

**Update:**

There is a new solution available.

Installation of the TEAM (Takari Extensions for Apache Maven) extensions, provides a thread-safe local repository and an improved algorithm for multi module builds.

See http://takari.io/book/30-team-maven.html#concurrent-safe-local-repository

Comment: Thanks mate, this is what I'm doing at this point in time, it seems to be working okay. However I just changed the global maven settings.xml file to instead point to a known location rather than ~/.m2/repository. It's been working but as you suggested there could be a point where there may be a clash :) Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Not recommended. Maven local repository is not supposed to be used concurrently. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-2802

Comment: Unless you have installed TEAM (Takari Extensions for Apache Maven). These extensions provide thread-safe local repository and an improved algorithm for multi module builds. I'm impressed, see http://takari.io/book/30-team-maven.html#concurrent-safe-local-repository

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this *directly* answers your concern, but it looks like what you're doing is correct.

From http://maven.apache.org/settings.html

> **localRepository**: This value is the path of this build system's local
>   repository. The default value is
>   ${user.home}/.m2/repository. This
>   element is especially useful for a
>   main build server allowing all
>   logged-in users to build from a common
>   local repository.

Comment: Thanks mate, didn't realise that the docs actually stated pretty much what we were doing, don't know how I missed that :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 
    --offline
option at command line.

Comment: that disables the remote repositories and leaves the local repo as the only place to resolve artifacts which is not what was asked.