# Avoid downloading plugins/unnecessary artifacts to Maven local repository

Tags: maven, maven-2, nexus

I am using Maven just as a package manager with a Nexus Sonatype Maven repository.

1. Installed Maven on Windows
2. Modified the settings.xml file to have a local repository at C:/nexus_repo.
3. Browsed to the maven bin folder and ran a sample command such as:

   **mvn.cmd dependency:purge-local-repository**
4. Maven now downloads the dependency plugin and related artifacts to the local repository. As a result I have lots of folders like "asm", "org", "commons-cli" etc in it.

All the binaries I manage are C++ binaries in a custom zip format and I was hoping to keep a clean local repository only mirroring the contents I have on the remote one. e.g. only a folder such as "com" followed by "mylibs" should be there. None of the binaries have any JAVA dependencies or any other dependency which should require all these unwanted plugin artifacts to be installed too.

Is there any way to modify this behavior so that Maven does not download the plugins it needs into my local repository?

Comment: No, I don't think you can do that. It needs to store them on disk. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238769/is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-local-maven-repository

Comment: @Tunaki: Yeah i am not looking to disable the local repo since I need it. I was thinking if it was possible to at least have a repo where you have all these plugin dependencies and a main local one where only my install stuff goes.

Comment: Well, if this is a separation of repo issue, I never used Nexus, but I know that in Artifactory you can create multiple repositories: remote repo would proxy Maven Central and store the artifacts downloaded by Maven and multiple local repositories to store your own artifacts. Probably you can do the same in Nexus.

Comment: You can do the same in Nexus...